# What does the vacuum hose below the EGR assembly on a 1997 Ford Escort attach to at either end?

Tags: ford, escort

I'm trying to figure out what the vacuum hose that attaches to some sort of assembly underneath the EGR on a 1997 Ford Escort with a 2.0 Split Port 2000 engine connects.  It is attached to the assembly under the EGR (or maybe it's the idle air control valve that is sitting above where it's connected), but the other end either broke off or came off and blind searching has resulted in no luck.

A vacuum hose diagram would be appreciated, but the ones I've found haven't been very useful.

EDIT: Rewrote the post as a question instead of a request for a resource to make it align better with SE Q/A format.

Comment: That's going to be a tall order in a short period of time. I did a cursory glance around the internet and came up with the same thing you did ... nothing. Hopefully someone has a diagram handy.

Comment: Yeah I know, I feel like it's basically asking for the moon here.  Neither of us are very mechanically inclined, and I'm 800 miles from the car.  The best I can tell is she's either describing the EGR valve or the IAC valve - and the hose she's having issues with is still attached to some sort of assembly that the valve is sitting on top of.

Comment: And thanks for adding the escort tag - I tried ford-escort and it didn't pop up, so I just left it at ford.  Newbie actions :/

Comment: There should be a vacuum diagram under the hood from the factory on a Ford! Try finding the serpentine belt diagram (above the grill), it should be somewhere near that. Have your family member see if they can find it and send you a picture.

Comment: Thanks @Jhawins, I will see if they can find something there.  I completely forgot that there are often diagrams in the compartment somewhere!

Comment: Now that you've had a little time in case someone would've been able to help... I don't think this question fits the format for this site, nor will this question/answer combo be useful to anyone else in the future. This is less a question than it is a request for resources and for that reason I don't think it belongs here.

Comment: You could be right.  I'm a newbie on this exchange.  I know on SO, resources are usually the answer.  I will edit the question to be more in line with a "help" question.

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, Autozone is actually great at this. They charge for membership to be able to access this information, but if you're able to aqquire a link to the specific page you need it will allow you to view all the information. BUT, if you navigate to a new page from there it will ask you to log in or sign up as a member.

Technically I think you're supposed to pay for it but they left it exposed. You can even find these diagrams in Google images, so I don't feel like it's wrong to post the image. Search for "autozone repair guide ford escort vacuum diagram" has turned up [this page](http://www.autozone.com/repairguides/Ford-Escort-Tracer-1991-1999-Repair-Guide/VACUUM-DIAGRAMS/VACUUM-DIAGRAMS/_/P-0900c1528008dcf6) which lists the diagrams of different engines/configurations from 1991-1999.

Judging from that page, the following diagram (which can also be found as the first image on Google images from the query "97 ford escort vacuum diagram") is correct. I believe the reason there is only one for the 1997 year is because they only used the 2.0 in that year. [image]

Comment: I found this, but only found it partially useful..  According to this, there is only one line going from the EGR to the EGR solenoid.  The line that is the problem is attached to something that is below what I am assuming is the EGR, and there is no depiction of this hose in this diagram.

Comment: Sadly this is probably the best you can hope for. There is often a vacuum line on the underside of the intake, where the airbox boot attaches. The way I see it if you know how the line is routed (its still attached at one end or is still wrapped around the same stuff) then you can get a rough idea of how far that hose would reach and search the potential areas very very well. Aside from that, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the diagram below, that the way many EGR's work is that there are two hoses, one which opens the valve when a particular set of conditions is met such as when engine temperature and manifold absolute pressure reach a certain threshold, and a second hose which connects to a regulator which prevents the intake from being flooded with too much exhaust gas which would choke the engine.  Exactly how it works varies from engine to engine, but that's the basic idea I think.  This is from page 272 of the book [Auto Fundamentals](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1566375770).

[image]